# How to delete/disable docker0 bridge on docker startup

Tags: docker, docker-network

Is there any way we can disable docker0 bridge on docker startup ?

Tried "bridge": "none" in daemon.json but its not working.

Also removed default docker bridge using "ip link delete docker0" but when we restart docker it came up automatically. So any permanent way to disable/delete default docker bridge on startup ?
I see the same question here [How to delete interface docker0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082608/how-to-delete-interface-docker0) but I already tried that and whenever docker is restarted the docker0 bridge came back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete interface docker0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082608/how-to-delete-interface-docker0)

Comment: No. The solution mentioned there not working.

Comment: I think I found the answer. Inorder to disable the default bridge network add `"bridge": "none"` in daemon.json and restart docker service. The changes will taken effect immediately if there is no running containers there. In my case there is some containers already running and these changes not taken effect. After inspecting the log, could see that  `info msg="There are old running containers, the network config will not take affect" `So I stopped the running container and restarted the docker service. After that bridge network is disabled. Hope this help someones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found the answer. Inorder to disable the default bridge network add `"bridge": "none"` in `daemon.json` and restart docker service. The changes will taken effect immediately if there are no running containers. In my case there were some containers already running, so changes not taken effect. After inspecting the log, could see that `info msg="There are old running containers, the network config will not take affect"` So I stopped the running container and restarted the docker service. After that bridge network is disabled. Hope this help someone.

Comment: Where is this documented? I could not find it

Comment: It is documented as part of the [dockerd documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#run-multiple-daemons), see the `--bridge` flag (which can be set via `daemon.json`, so same semantics apply.

Answer (score 14):

Create file `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
    "bridge": "none"
}
```

And restart docker:
`systemctl restart docker`

Comment: Is it documented somewhere? I could not find it anywhere. In addition, why are you disabling the `iptables` changes?

Comment: `"iptables": false` is not needed! adding this iptables would end up docker containers without internet connection